# Unit Testing Android Studio

Tags: java, unit-testing, android

I am carrying out unit testing for my project but i am not sure i am doing it correctly. The example below calculates the difference between 2 time duration's.

```
public void diffTime2() throws Exception {

        //Calculsates the difference
        String ExpectedResult = "1:0:0";
        String str_time1 = "04 13, 2018 09:00:00";
        String str_time2 = "04 13, 2018 08:00:00";
        DateFormat simpleDateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat3.parse(str_time1);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat3.parse(str_time2);
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date2);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date1);
        long hours = (Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24);
        long mins = (Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60);
        long secs = (Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60);
        String result = (hours+":"+mins+":"+secs);
        //System.out.println(hours+":"+mins+":"+secs);


        assertEquals(ExpectedResult, result);
}
```

It successfully runs and seems to be OKbut i am not sure that i am completing the unit testing exactly how i should.

[image: This is the result that is returned]

Any observation about this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- **This is not a unit test of your code.** A unit test must at some point involve some part of your code, and it looks like this test uses only classes which exist in the Java SDK. The idea is *not* to check an idea for an implementation, but instead to detect bugs in your *actual* implementation.
- By convention instance variables use `camelCase` in Java, so `ExpectedResult` should be `expectedResult` and `str_time2` should be `strTime2`.
- Maybe it's necessary, but I'm sceptical of the need for the conversion from `Date` to `DateTime`.